# Emacs web-mode indent inline javascript

Tags: javascript, emacs

I have just started using Emacs to edit my HTML, and so I downloaded [web-mode](http://www.web-mode.org). I was going to write some javascript in a `<script>` tag, but I found that the javascript inside the tag did not auto-indent. Example:

```
<script>
function example() {
/*This is not indented in emacs*/
}
</script>
```

Is there a way I can make this indent? If so, how? Thanks for any possible help.

Comment: @fzzle I am trying to stick with emacs for the moment.

Comment: Report this an issue in the `web-mode` github repo in [Here](https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode/issues/new)
Seems like a bug.

Comment: Are you sure that web-mode is active ? Try `M-x web-mode`.

Comment: Make sure that your `<script>` tag is closed *before* you start typing any javascript. Also, does the same thing happen if you start emacs with the `-Q` option, run `M-x package-initialize` and then switch into `web-mode`? I was able to reproduce your issue when I had not yet added a closing `</script>`, but once I did that I do get indentation.

Comment: After entering the closing script tag, try `M-x indent-region`.